# How to set headers In URL to call image

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Before this, I already call the image with URL without the headers. It looks like this:

**javascript**

```
$scope.image = "http://my.address";
```

**html**

```
<img ng-src="{{image}}">
```

Then, I tried to get the image with headers:

```
headers: {
  'x-access-token': 'token'
}
```

So, my javascript looks like this:

**javascript**

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  timeout: 25000,
  url: "http://my.address",
  headers: {
    'x-access-token': 'token'
  }
})

.success(function (data) {
   $scope.image = data;
})

.error(function (error) {
  //Error handling
});
```

Then, the result is my html did not show the actual image. It only shows the **white blank image**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I don't know angular**, but isn't `$http` an simple [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) wrapper ?

If so, `data` should be the raw data of your image, which can't be understood by the HTMLImage's `src` attribute. This attribute only accepts URI.
You can probably circumvent this with the `responseType` option of XHR, also present in `$http` if we trust [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage).

Then something like

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  timeout: 25000,
  url: "http://my.address",
  headers: {
    'x-access-token': 'token'
  },
  responseType: 'blob' // request a Blob instead of raw data
})

.success(function (blob) {
   $scope.image = URL.createObjectURL(blob); // create a temp URI for this Blob
})

.error(function (error) {
  //Error handling
});
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The value of ng-src is interpolated. You need to surround it in double curly braces like so:

```
<img ng-src="{{image}}">
```

[Working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZbvEaG5GmyqvgLCPOeWZ?p=preview)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to insert it in my question. I already put it in my actual code. Thanks. But I'm still can't figure it out how to put the headers together with url link.

Answer (score -1):

ng-src expects a url but you give it an raw image, so it does not know what to do with this. You need to add `data:[<mime type>][;charset][;base64],<Data>` at the beginning of the image so ng-src knows what to do with it.

Example: data:image/png,kjbaskljbasd4dd64ad464d6a...kajbkjbd8ad76

```
$scope.image = "data:image/png," + data;
```